# How to create a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am a new to JSON and facing problems creating a very simple array.

I have the key,value pair received from an HTML form:

```
frm1 = {"fname":"John","lname":"Doe","location":"CA"};
frm2 = {"fname":"Jenny","lname":"Doe","location":"CA"};
```

I want to create a JSON like below:

```
{
  "employee":[
    {"fname":"John","lname":"Doe","location":"CA"},
    {"fname":"Jenny","lname":"Doe","location":"CA"}
]}
```

Trying to push the first form data(`frm1`) only by below code is not working.

```
var form1 = {"employee":[]};

form1.employee = frm1;

console.log(JSON.stringify(form1)); // prints form1 :{"employee" : ["fname","lname","location"]}
```

Only keys are printed. Please suggest.

Comment: Just to clarify: What you're working with are pure Javascript objects and arrays, not JSON. JSON is a *textual* format used to exchange data objects.

Comment: do i have to parse it then?

Comment: Well, that depends on if you're working with objects (as in the example) or strings (which may contain JSON). `console.log(typeof frm1)` will say either `object` or `string`. E.g. `console.log(typeof '{"fname": "john"}')` will say it's a string which needs to be parsed whereas `console.log(typeof {"fname": "john"})` will say that it's a good ol' object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply them

```
var form1 = { employee: [frm1, frm2] };
```

Answer (score 2):

Either create the object with array elements

```js
var frm1 = {
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "location": "CA"
  },
  frm2 = {
    "fname": "Jenny",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "location": "CA"
  };

var form1 = {
  "employee": [frm1, frm2]
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(form1));
```

---

or push elements later using **[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)**

```js
var frm1 = {
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "location": "CA"
  },
  frm2 = {
    "fname": "Jenny",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "location": "CA"
  };
var form1 = {
  "employee": []
};
form1.employee.push(frm1,frm2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(form1));
```

Comment: `push` accepts multiple arguments: `form1.employee.push(frm1, frm2)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var frm1 = {"fname":"John","lname":"Doe","location":"CA"}; 
    var frm2 = {"fname":"John","lname":"Doe","location":"CA"}; 
    var form1 = {"employee":[" ",""]};
  

    form1["employee"][0] = frm1;
    form1["employee"][1] = frm2;
    
  
     console.log(form1["employee"][0]);
    console.log(form1);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(form1));
```

*Since the keys value is an array you can use push or use its array index*

Sorry I misunderstood the question you want an array with multiple values for single object for employee